# Pipe output from Process into GUI

Tags: python, multiprocessing, locking, pyqt4

I am writing a PyQt4 based launcher.  When clicking a button in the launcher start_tool is called. this function opens an new terminal, executing anoother tool. hence two new windows are openend, the terminal and the newly started tool. I now want to pipe the output of the new terminal into a textedit of the launcher in order to track the errors WITHIN the launcher. I need to be able to operate both the launcher and the started tool at the same time.

I have tried following code, it pipes some output but then an "FATAL IO error: client killed" is thrown and the launcher is killed.

```
    def f(self, lock, tools):
        try:
            lock.acquire()
            ex = sub.Popen(tools, shell=True,stdout=sub.PIPE,stderr=sub.STDOUT)
            p = os.getpid()
            while True:
                output = ex.stdout.readline().decode()
                if output == '' and ex.poll() is not None:
                    break
                if output:
                        self.console_launcher.insertPlainText(output)
                        QtGui.QApplication.processEvents()
            lock.release()
        except sub.CalledProcessError as e:
            lock.acquire()
            print(e)
            lock.release()
        finally:
            lock.release()

    def start_tool(self):
        lock = mp.Lock()
        tools = ['gnome-terminal --tab -- shells/program.sh']
        p = mp.Process(target=self.f, args=(lock, tools))
        p.start()
        p.join()
```

I want to pipe the output of Tool B into the Gui of tool A. Both are PyQt4 based apps and need to run separetly.

Comment: Widgets are not thread safe (and a new process always involves a related new thread): you can only access widgets from the current thread (and, thus, the current process). You cannot even call `processEvents()` from there. Either use signals connected to the function that just adds the text, or use QProcess.

Comment: Hi, i have now used QProcess. it works when running Program A and B in Parralell. But I habe another Prgram C, D, E .. that need to be started from Program A. As soon as I create another QProcess it kills the old one. Will I have the same issue with with signal ? @musicamente